# Вопрос про ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Привет, мне необходимо обновить все фрагменты viewpager. Делаю это через `setAdapter(adapter);` Но после обновления пропадает `PagerTitleStrip`. При свайпе на другую страницу `viewpager PagerTitleStrip` восстанавливается.

Как такое может произойти? Надо ли удалять все страницы ViewPager'a перед обновлении его через `setAdapter`?

Comment: нужно больше информации, желательно куски самого кода, что происходит внутри вашего `Adapter`, `onCreateView` фрагмента в котором находится адаптер(как создается адаптер)?

Comment: или хотя бы покажите что вы передаете конструктору `Adapter`

Answer (score 1):

Так как пока нету достаточно информации сделаю предположение, что вы используете фрагменты внутри фрагментов. В таком случае при создание `Adapter` ему в конструктор следует передать `getChildFragmentManager()` вместо `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: так я так и передаю

Answer (score 0):

может не стоит адаптер использовать? Вы же обновлять собираетесь фрагменты… viewpager при этом не обязательно перезаполнять…
можно, например, получить все свои фрагменты и обновить их (вызвать onCreateView, ну или другой метод, где происходит инициация данных Ваших фрагментов)

Comment: у меня при обновлении может измениться количество фрагментов

Comment: а это не важно… у Вас же есть коллекция фрагментов… можно получить их всех и обновить в цикле…
или у Вас они в принципе уничтожаются и другие фрагменты образуются?

Comment: фрагменты такие же, только например если раньше у меня было 2 фрагмента, то при обновлении их может стать 3 и наоборот. Т.е. у меня при обновлении добавляется количество фрагментов или удаляется.

Comment: у Вас есть адаптер - тот, который параметр тут "setAdapter(adapter);"
у этого адаптера есть метод getCount() - это получите количество фрагментов. в цикле перебирайте их опять же методом адаптера getItem() - так Вы получите Ваш фрагмент, и у него соответственно вызывайте onCreateView

Comment: а если мне нужно изменить количество фрагментов?

Comment: так Вам надо перерисовать viewPager или просто обновить данные в тех фрагментах, что уже отрисованы?

Comment: после метода setAdapter я обычно принудительно выставляю текущую страницу setCurrentItem(0)
может так заставит явно титулы выстроиться правильно

Comment: полностью перерисовать, т.е. у меня может измениться количество страниц в ViewPager.

Comment: попробуйте после setAdapter вызвать setCurrentItem(0), это в свою очередь должно вызвать 
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ………
    }
адаптера и соответственно, перерисовать титулы

Comment: я так и делаю: mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
кстати, если поставить setCurrentItem(0), то перерисовывается хорошо, пустые титулы только когда я хочу поставить последнюю страницу как текущую.

Comment: а у вас у всех страниц/фрагментов имена есть...в смысле `getPageTitle` для всех возвращает что нибудь?

Comment: Да, для всех возвращает.

Comment: такое ощущение, что адаптер не создал предыдущую страницу…попробуйте setCurrentItem() последовательно на предпоследнюю страницу, а потом на последнюю…

Comment: вы какой адаптер используете?
FragmentStatePagerAdapter или FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: @evp FragmentState

Comment: @evp пробовал на предпоследнюю/последнюю - один и тот же эффект. Title даже не создается, только содержимое фрагмента создается.

Comment: он при свайпе удаляет фрагменты +- 2 от текущего, насколько я помню. Если фрагментов не много может стоит пользовать FragmentPagerAdapter…

Comment: @evp с FragmentPagerAdapter эффект тот же, title для последней страницы создается только в момент свайпа

Comment: public static class какой-то майАдаптер extends FragmentPagerAdapter

можно глянуть на этот класс?

Comment: Сделал так: new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                    }
                });
теперь все отображается нормально, но получился некрасивый эффект: в начале показывается 1 страница, а потом перескакивает на последнюю.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mm98c1D3 вот тот класс

Comment: тогда как вариант, можно добавлять не в конец, а в начало и пользовать уже setCurrentItem(0)

Comment: титулы вроде бы как устанавливаются но не совсем понятно, почему таблицы создаются асинхронно… тут может получиться и ответ, потому как гетКаунт может сработать до того, как таблицы создадутся и count = tableNames.size(); - даст ноль

Comment: Я загружаю данные таблицы из базы данных, поэтому запустил их в отдельном потоке

Comment: тогда стоит весь адаптер создавать в отдельном потоке, а не отдельную его часть.
Создавайте класс SectionsPagerAdapter в отдельном потоке, но внутри него, в конструкторе уберите разделение потоков, чтобы гетКаунт не сработал до того как завершится конструктор

Comment: ничего не изменилось. запустил в новом потоке handler mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
                            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);

Comment: в самом классе адаптера убрал получение данных в другом потоке

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22888/discussion-on-answer-by-evp---viewpager).